# Command to search a part of value in a table in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The LIKE condition allows us to use wildcards in the WHERE clause of an SQL statement. This allows us to perform pattern matching. Like this

```
SELECT description FROM projects WHERE description LIKE '%hello%';
```

like the same above operation, any query is available for Cassandra in CLI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970427/regular-expression-search-or-like-type-feature-in-cassandra

Comment: Use Cassandra SASI index https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of SASI index to do this type "LIKE" querying. SASI was an improvement open sourced (contributed by Apple) to Cassandra community. This index gets created for every SSTable being flushed to disk and doesn't maintain a separate table. Hence less disk usage, no separate memtable/bloom filter/partition index (less memory) and minimal overhead.

Essentially there are three modes

PREFIX - Used to serve LIKE queries based on prefix of indexed column
CONTAINS - Used to serve LIKE queries based on whether the search term exists in the indexed column
SPARSE - Used to index data that is sparse (every term/column value has less than 5 matching keys). For example range queries that span large timestamps.

With this Index on say "description" column, you can satisfy query

> SELECT description FROM projects WHERE description LIKE '%hello%';

[Reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) documentation on SASI index.